# New instance of service for each component in Angular 5

Tags: angular5

I want to put all my  logic in service from component. Is there way to have local service for each component

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you  want local  instance for your component , what you can do is - 
 you can use Providers:[SimpleService] metadata in you @component decorator.

```
 @Component({
 selector: 'parent',
 template: `...`,
 providers: [ SimpleService ]
})
class ParentComponent {
  constructor(private service: SimpleService) { }
}
```

Each instance of ParentComponent now has it’s own instance of SimpleService, so state is not shared globally but only between a ParentComponent and it’s child components.